# How to dynamically add em tag before img?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to put em tag before IMG tag dynamically , the image class is .photo.

```
<img class="photo" src="image.jpg" />
```

I want to convert this to

```
<em></em><img class="photo" src="image.jpg" />
```

using jQuery, I am using the append but its add the em in the img tag,

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("img").before("em")
```

**EDIT:** Okay, no need to add the closing tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("img.photo").before("<em>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the before() method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use before()